# Extract subarray between certain value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of values that are the result of merging many files. I need to pad some of the values. I know that each sub-section begins with the value -1. I am trying to basically extract a sub-array between -1's in the main array via iteration.

For example supposed this is the main list:

```
-1 1 2 3 4 5 7 -1 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 -1 0 2 3 5 -1
```

I would like to extract the values between the -1s:

```
list_a = 1 2 3 4 5 7
list_b = 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8
list_c = 0 2 3 5 ...
list_n = a1 a2 a3 ... aM
```

I have extracted the indices for each -1 by searching through the main list:

```
minus_ones = [i for i, j in izip(count(), q) if j == -1]
```

I also assembled them as pairs using a common recipe:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a,b)

for index in pairwise(minus_ones):
    print index
```

The next step I am trying to do is grab the values between the index pairs, for example:

```
 list_b: (7 , 16) -> 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8
```

so I can then do some work to those values (I will add a fixed int. to each value in each sub-array).

Comment: There should be a way to build the list of lists while merging the files thus avoiding this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned `numpy` in the tags.  If you're using it, have a look at [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, -1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, -1, 0, 2,
               3, 5, -1])
arrays = np.split(x, np.where(x == -1)[0])
arrays = [item[1:] for item in arrays if len(item) > 1]
```

This yields:

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]),
 array([4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8]),
 array([0, 2, 3, 5])]
```

What's going on is that `where` will yield an array (actually a tuple of arrays, therefore the `where(blah)[0]`) of the indicies where the given expression is true.  We can then pass these indicies to `split` to get a sequence of arrays.

However, the result will contain the `-1`'s and an empty array at the start, if the sequence starts with `-1`. Therefore, we need to filter these out.

If you're not already using `numpy`, though, your (or @DSM's) `itertools` solution is probably a better choice.

Comment: Interesting. If I wanted to then pad all arrays after the first, it would look kinda like this loop :     for i in arrays : new = len(array[i-1]) + array[i] ?

Comment: @user2221667 - By "pad", do you mean make all the arrays the same length?  (e.g. `[0, 2, 3, 5]` --> `[0, 2, 3, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1]`) If so, have a look at `numpy.pad`.  However, at that point, it might make more sense to just use a 2D array of the right size and set the first N elements of each row to the values in your array. For example: `x = np.zeros((num_arrays, max_len)); for i, item in enumerate(arrays): x[i, :len(item)] = item`. (That's a bit unreadable in comment form, sorry.)

Comment: Thanks, Ok ONE more question. Lets say I make these lists, do some work to them, how do I get them back together at the end so that each array is between a -1? Should I use np.concatenate?

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the groups themselves and don't care about the indices of the groups (you could always reconstruct them, after all), I'd use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> seq = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, -1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, -1, 0, 2, 3, 5, -1]
>>> groups = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x != -1) if k]
>>> groups
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8], [0, 2, 3, 5]]
```

I missed the `numpy` tags, though: if you're working with numpy arrays, using `np.split`/`np.where` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this, which is a little different from the path you started down:

```
input_list = [-1,1,2,3,4,5,7,-1,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,-1,0,2,3,5,-1]

list_index = -1
new_lists = []
for i in input_list:
    if i == -1:
        list_index += 1
        new_lists.append([])
        continue
    else:
        print list_index
        print new_lists
        new_lists[list_index].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you build your `list`, you can directly add the values to a `string`. So rather than starting with a `list` like `xx = []`, you can start with `xx = ''`, and then do an update like `xx = xx + ' ' + str (val)`. The result will be a `string` rather than a `list`. Then, you can just use the `split()` method on the strihg.

```
In [48]: xx
Out[48]: '-1 1 2 3 4 5 7 -1 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 -1 0 2 3 5 -1'

In [49]: xx.split('-1')
Out[49]: ['', ' 1 2 3 4 5 7 ', ' 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 ', ' 0 2 3 5 ', '']

In [50]: xx.split('-1')[1:-1]
Out[50]: [' 1 2 3 4 5 7 ', ' 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 ', ' 0 2 3 5 ']
```

Am sure you can take it from here ...